# SQL to SELECT last 4 Financial Quarters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, refactoring, finance

I'm learning SQL and I have this horrible looking query to select the last 4 financial/fiscal quarters and how many quarters ago they were.

- This is using Australian financial year (June - July)
- The Financial Year 2018 is July 2017 to June 2018
- FinancialQuarterID is structured like YYYYQ

If the date is 28th March 2018 then the table returned is like:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗  
║   ║ ID         ║ QuartersAgo ║  
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣  
║ 1 ║ 20182      ║ 1           ║  
║ 2 ║ 20181      ║ 2           ║  
║ 3 ║ 20174      ║ 3           ║  
║ 4 ║ 20173      ║ 4           ║  
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

My query is below. Surely there is a much better and more efficient way... What I like about this is that it works and I can commit it to version control (unlike Excel and PowerBI that I would usually build this thing in).

In the first phase I am determining the financial year based on the month of the calendar year.

In a similar way I am then breaking the years down into Quarters to determine the current financial quarter.

Once I have found that I am setting and determining values for the nth quarter ago.

What I don't like is that I feel like I should just be inserting values into the variable table as I am determining which quarter I am. Instead I assign to a value and then insert that later on.

```
DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE();

DECLARE @ThisCalendarYear VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @ThisFinancialYear VARCHAR(4)
DECLARE @ThisCalendarMonth INT

DECLARE @Last4FinancialQuarters TABLE(
    ID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    QuartersAgo INT NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @LastFinancialQuarter VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @SecondLastFinancialQuarter VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @ThirdLastFinancialQuarter VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @FourthLastFinancialQuarter VARCHAR(5)

SET @ThisCalendarYear = DatePart(Year, @Today)
SET @ThisCalendarMonth = DatePart(Month, @Today)

IF DatePart(Month, @Today) <= 6
  SET @ThisFinancialYear = DatePart(Year, @Today)
ELSE 
  SET @ThisFinancialYear = DatePart(Year, @Today) +1 

SET @LastFinancialQuarter = CASE
  WHEN  @ThisCalendarMonth <= 3 THEN CONCAT(@ThisCalendarYear     ,4 - 2)
  WHEN  @ThisCalendarMonth <= 6 THEN CONCAT(@ThisCalendarYear     ,4 - 1)
  WHEN  @ThisCalendarMonth <= 9 THEN CONCAT(@ThisCalendarYear     ,4 - 0)
  WHEN  @ThisCalendarMonth <= 12 THEN CONCAT(@ThisCalendarYear + 1,4 - 3)
END

SET @SecondLastFinancialQuarter = CASE
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 4 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear,3)
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 3 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear,2)
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 2 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear,1)
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 4 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear - 1,4)
END

SET @ThirdLastFinancialQuarter = CASE
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 4 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear,2)
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 3 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear,1)
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 2 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear - 1,4)
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 4 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear - 1,3)
END

SET @FourthLastFinancialQuarter = CASE
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 4 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear,1)
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 3 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear - 1,4)
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 2 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear - 1,3)
  WHEN SUBSTRING(@LastFinancialQuarter, 5,1) = 4 THEN CONCAT(@ThisFinancialYear - 1,2)
END


INSERT INTO @Last4FinancialQuarters (ID, QuartersAgo)
VALUES
    (@LastFinancialQuarter, 1),
    (@SecondLastFinancialQuarter, 2),
    (@ThirdLastFinancialQuarter, 3),
    (@FourthLastFinancialQuarter, 4);

SELECT * FROM @Last4FinancialQuarters
```

Would appreciate some feedback :) Thanks

Comment: Can you also show us sample input data from your source table?

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen, I actually don't have any data source for this. I just use GETDATE() and PARTDATE() to pull from SQL Date function. Then storing the output in a T-SQL variable table.

Comment: Ultimately, I then use this table to perform my inner joins on other sales/customer type tables with date table and then to this in memory Financial Quarter table. There is probably a better way to do that whole pattern like adding FinancialQuarterID to the dbo.dimDate (which I am currently getting someone else to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursive CTE to the rescue:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 1 as QuartersAgo, GETDATE() as DT, 
        CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 3, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEADD(MONTH, 3, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(1)) as FinancialQuarter
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT QuartersAgo + 1, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, cte.DT), 
        CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 3, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, cte.DT))) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEADD(MONTH, 3, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, cte.DT))) AS VARCHAR(1))
    FROM cte
    WHERE QuartersAgo < 4
)
SELECT FinancialQuarter, QuartersAgo FROM cte
```

Here's the output:

```
FinancialQuarter    QuartersAgo
20182               1
20181               2
20174               3
20173               4
```

Here are some important points:

1. To get today's date as an Australian fiscal quarter, add 3 months and concat the year to the quarter (which you can get with DATEPART(QUARTER(DATE)), so, like this:

   CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 3, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(QUARTER, DATEADD(MONTH, 3, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(1))
2. A CTE (common table expression) is kind of like a temp table
   that's in scope for a query. That's a simplistic explanation. CTEs
   are worth reading about!
3. You can create a recursive CTE using
   UNION ALL - the part of the query before the UNION ALL is the
   anchor, and the recursive part comes after. In this case, I use
   WHERE QuartersAgo < 4 to stop the query from recursing after a few
   unions.
4. The CTE starts with ;WITH - all CTEs start with "WITH",
   and the semicolon just terminates any hanging chads that were
   dangling in front of the CTE definition.
5. After the parentheses
   surrounding the CTE definition, you can query from the CTE. But only
   once. After that, the CTE is out of scope.
6. It's possible to nest
   a bunch of CTEs - a CTE can refer to CTEs that precede it, but not
   those that follow it.

Comment: What is `cte`? Also why start with a `;`? Is that just best practice or does it do something besides end any potential other query running?

Comment: `CTE` is `common table expression`. Please look for `CTE` on google.

Comment: Sorry it just looks so much better than what I was doing. Are you able to explain a little what is happening?

Comment: Sure! I'll add some comments above.

Comment: It starts with `;` because in SQL server it is not mandatory to end every statement with `;` but `CTE` syntax requires previous statement to be terminated with `;`.

Comment: I appreciate it! You've  given some real gold here. Thanks @MaxSzczurek

Comment: In your opinion, is this something SQL gurus actually do... ie Have a query at hand for pulling last n months, quarters, years etc 

Orr is this something most people opt to put into the database table (ie dimDate) and run joins against that rather than in memory var tables?

Comment: That mostly depends on scope. CTEs last for about 1 query. If you need some recursive magic to make a single query work, in a stored procedure or something, by all means, use one. It'd be cumbersome to maintain a date dimension just for that purpose. If you're talking about a data warehouse or something, you'd want to persist a date dimension rather than building a recursive CTE each time.

Comment: Thanks mate. You've given me plenty more to read up on. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I have also use `Recursive CTE` to solve this query (I did take help from above @Max solution)-

```
declare @Today date = getdate()
declare @CalendarMonth int = datepart(month, @Today)
declare @LastFinancialQuarterDate date = dateadd(month, (case when @CalendarMonth <= 6 then 6 else 18 end) - @CalendarMonth, @Today)

;with cte as
(
    select  cast(datepart(year, @LastFinancialQuarterDate) as varchar(4))
            +
            cast(datepart(quarter, @LastFinancialQuarterDate) as varchar(1)) as ID,
            1 as QuartersAgo
    union all
    select  cast(datepart(year, dateadd(month, cte.QuartersAgo * -3, @LastFinancialQuarterDate)) as varchar(4))
            +
            cast(datepart(quarter, dateadd(month, cte.QuartersAgo * -3, @LastFinancialQuarterDate)) as varchar(1)) as ID,
            (cte.QuartersAgo + 1) as QuartersAgo
    from cte
    where cte.QuartersAgo < 4
)
select * from cte
```

First thing I did is to find date which belongs to last Australian quarter and set it to `@LastFinancialQuarterDate` variable. After that I have use that variable in `Recursive CTE` to traverse last four quarters.